# Issue in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure blob storage to migrate csv files to azure SQL Database. Data will updated to this Blob storage account every month.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know the source for that blob storage. For last month the no data is uploaded, so I don't know where the issue occurred. Is there any possibility to find where is the source for that blob?

I couldn't try anything because I couldn't recognize the problem.

Comment: You need to clarify some things. Where is the data coming from? Are you managing the uploading process to Azure blob storage? Do you use SAS tokens? Do you even own the storage? To much information missing.

Comment: Sorry for that, because I doesn't own the storage, my job is to ensure the blob is updated and I have created a adf pipeline to move those csv files to azure SQL DataBase. I have no  idea about from where the data is coming in, but i'm sure that the process of data flow into the blob is automated. Probabily it may be a power automate flow. These initial process of connecting the blob and an external source were not done by me. Now I'm tasked to find why the Blob is not getting updated with new files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Eric Qvarnstrom too much information is missing like SAS tokens and where is the data coming from.

```
Is there any possibility to find where is the source for that blob? and For last month the no data is uploaded,
```

- AFAIK it is not possible to find where the data is coming from. For that you need to check with Source owners or the Stack holders who are placing files in storage.
- Also Check the keys shared with source system are expired and if no data is uploaded check with that source data team are they facing any issues in uploading new data this month.
- I would suggest you set alerts rule to track the Create/Update Storage Account (Storage Accounts) to notify you next time.

As Shown in below images Under Monitoring blade select Alerts> Create> Alert Rule.
[image]
After selecting Create an alert rule under scope select your storage account and under condition select Create/Update Storage Account (Storage Accounts) as shown below.
[image]
[image]
Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?tabs=metric) to create a new alert rule.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have permission to do this work. I think this could solve the problem. Let me ask my client about this idea.